# How can I populate my fullcalendar with the data in my postgresql using node; express framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, fullcalendar

I want to load the data from my database into my full calendar, but I don't know to do it in JavaScript. Every code I find is for PHP, and since I'm trying to apply it to Node Express framework I don't get to display the data from the database into my full calendar.

This is my script for my full calendar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var Fullcalendar = (function() {

      var $calendar = $('[data-toggle="calendar"]');

      function init($this) {

        var events = [

        {
         id: 1,
         title: 'Call with Dave',
         start: '2019-05-18',
         allDay: true,
         className: 'bg-red',
         description: 'Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.'
       },

       ],

      // Full calendar options
    // For more options read the official docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs


    options = {
      header: {
        right: '',
        center: '',
        left: 'title, today'
      },
      buttonIcons: {
        prev: 'calendar--prev',
        next: 'calendar--next'
      },
      defaultView: 'month',
      theme: false,
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      editable: true,
      events: events,

      dayClick: function(date) {
        var isoDate = moment(date).toISOString();
        $('#new-event').modal('show');
        $('.new-event--title').val('');
        $('.new-event--start').val(isoDate);
        $('.new-event--end').val(isoDate);
      },

      viewRender: function(view) {
        var calendarDate = $this.fullCalendar('getDate');
        var calendarMonth = calendarDate.month();

        //Set data attribute for header. This is used to switch header images using css
        // $this.find('.fc-toolbar').attr('data-calendar-month', calendarMonth);

        //Set title in page header
        $('.fullcalendar-title').html(view.title);
      },

      // Edit calendar event action

      eventClick: function(event, element) {
        $('#edit-event input[value=' + event.className + ']').prop('checked', true);
        $('#edit-event').modal('show');
        $('.edit-event--id').val(event.id);
        $('.edit-event--title').val(event.title);
        $('.edit-event--description').val(event.description);
      }
    };

    // Initalize the calendar plugin
    $this.fullCalendar(options);


    //
    // Calendar actions
    //


    //Add new Event

    $('body').on('click', '.new-event--add', function() {
      var eventTitle = $('.new-event--title').val();

      // Generate ID
      var GenRandom = {
        Stored: [],
        Job: function() {
          var newId = Date.now().toString().substr(6); // or use any method that you want to achieve this string

          if (!this.Check(newId)) {
            this.Stored.push(newId);
            return newId;
          }
          return this.Job();
        },
        Check: function(id) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.Stored.length; i++) {
            if (this.Stored[i] == id) return true;
          }
          return false;
        }
      };

      if (eventTitle != '') {
        $this.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
          id: GenRandom.Job(),
          title: eventTitle,
          start: $('.new-event--start').val(),
          end: $('.new-event--end').val(),
          allDay: true,
          className: $('.event-tag input:checked').val()
        }, true);

        $('.new-event--form')[0].reset();
        $('.new-event--title').closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
        $('#new-event').modal('hide');
      } else {
        $('.new-event--title').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-danger');
        $('.new-event--title').focus();
      }
    });


    //Update/Delete an Event
    $('body').on('click', '[data-calendar]', function() {
      var calendarAction = $(this).data('calendar');
      var currentId = $('.edit-event--id').val();
      var currentTitle = $('.edit-event--title').val();
      var currentDesc = $('.edit-event--description').val();
      var currentClass = $('#edit-event .event-tag input:checked').val();
      var currentEvent = $this.fullCalendar('clientEvents', currentId);

      //Update
      if (calendarAction === 'update') {
        if (currentTitle != '') {
          currentEvent[0].title = currentTitle;
          currentEvent[0].description = currentDesc;
          currentEvent[0].className = [currentClass];

          console.log(currentClass);
          $this.fullCalendar('updateEvent', currentEvent[0]);
          $('#edit-event').modal('hide');
        } else {
          $('.edit-event--title').closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
          $('.edit-event--title').focus();
        }
      }

      //Delete
      if (calendarAction === 'delete') {
        $('#edit-event').modal('hide');

        // Show confirm dialog
        setTimeout(function() {
          swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            buttonsStyling: false,
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-danger',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
            cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-secondary'
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
              // Delete event
              $this.fullCalendar('removeEvents', currentId);

              // Show confirmation
              swal({
                title: 'Deleted!',
                text: 'The event has been deleted.',
                type: 'success',
                buttonsStyling: false,
                confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary'
              });
            }
          })
        }, 200);
      }
    });


    //Calendar views switch
    $('body').on('click', '[data-calendar-view]', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('[data-calendar-view]').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var calendarView = $(this).attr('data-calendar-view');
      $this.fullCalendar('changeView', calendarView);
    });


    //Calendar Next
    $('body').on('click', '.fullcalendar-btn-next', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this.fullCalendar('next');
    });


    //Calendar Prev
    $('body').on('click', '.fullcalendar-btn-prev', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $this.fullCalendar('prev');
    });
  }


  //
  // Events
  //

  // Init
  if ($calendar.length) {
    init($calendar);
  }

})();

</script>
```

So I want to create a for loop to get the data values and replace the values of events from the one in the database

```
var events = [

        {
         id: 1,
         title: 'Call with Dave',
         start: '2019-05-18',
         allDay: true,
         className: 'bg-red',
         description: 'Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.'
       },

       ],
```

Comment: If you can learn how you write a database query using nodeJS, get the results and turn them into JSON then you have got the answer. Doesn't need to be specific to fullCalendar, the process is the same

Answer (score 0):

have you tried on the full calendar configuration on the page

```
 <%event.forEach(function(item, index) { %>    events:   [
                    { // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object
                   
    {
     id: <%= item.id%>,
     title: '<%= item.title%>',
     start: '<%= item.start%>',
     allDay: <%= item.allDay%>,
     className: '<%= item.className%>',
     description: '<%= item.description%>'
   }
                }
            ]
 <% }); %>
```

Using the sequelize library you can do CRUD operations and when you render your page on node like this

```
res.render('/calendar', {
            pageTitle: 'Calendar',
            event: event  //the result of the db query,
```

the event rendered here is the one that you got from the DB

please also try read
https://node-postgres.com/ its the postgre DB nodejs documentation and https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/getting-started/ a very useful nodejs sql library

Comment: Please format your code correctly. I have no idea where to begin editing.

Comment: sorry for that. try using [sequelize] (sequelize.org/master) bold it will connect node to the db also aid in CRUD. Its easier and safer. After you do a query just render the data for the front with ejs using the for each statement . also try reading https://node-postgres.com/ its the postgre nodejs library